# STUFF function to concatenate values

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

The STUFF function & FOR XML PATH has been discussed before. My case is slightly involved as there is a many-to-relationship between T1 and T2

Table T1(t1id, t1name) T2(t2id, t2name)
Lets say there is an intermediate link table also F(t1id, t2id)

The output that I am looking for is as follows:

T1id1 -> t2name1,t2name3,t2name6 for all ids in T1

Can this be done in a single query?

Thanks
Anand

I added some sample data

### Table Geography

```
Id  Name
---------------
1   All
2   APR
3   EMEA
4   Pan Asia
5   Japan
6   China
7   European
8   US
```

### Table Analyst

```
Id   Name
-------------
1    Tom
2    Dick
3    Harry
4    Peter
5    Mary
6    Amy
7    Susie
```

These 2 tables are N->M

The output I am looking for is

```
Analyst.Id   Analyst.Name  Geography.Name
------------------------------------------
1            Tom           EMEA, China
2            Dick          APR, US, China
....
....
```

Comment: how could you say that `Tom` has two  `Geography.Name (EMEA, China)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488401/sql-server-concatenate-rows-using-many-to-many-related-tables

Comment: Same question answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488401/sql-server-concatenate-rows-using-many-to-many-related-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488401/sql-server-concatenate-rows-using-many-to-many-related-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. like this

```
SELECT T1.t1id, STUFF(t2.name, 1, 1, '')
FROM   T1
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT ',' + T2.name
           FROM   T2
           WHERE  T2.t2id = T1.t1id
           FOR XML PATH ('')
       ) t2 (name)
```